# How do I set a decorator for every one of my Django views?

Tags: python, django, oop, decorator

Suppose I have 20 views inside views.py

How do I set a decorator on top of each function? Without manually pasting one on top?

Comment: Okay, amuse us. **Why** can you not paste 1 line multiple times? It's one keypress (`P`).

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of this decorator is and also that it applies to all your views all of the time?

Answer (score 0):

I found a discussion regarding this here: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/2cff3374d365998d/24cd8b86b73d3832?lnk=raot&pli=1

The general conclusion is that you could write some code to auto-apply your decorator to all views, but that in general it is not worth the trouble and later confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate all your views in urls.py: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/532/ .