# Is there a more concise notation than decorators to have a function called before any view function

Tags: python, django, django-views

All of my view functions require the django request object to pass some tests. Is there a shorter notation for this than putting a

```
@request_passes_test(always_the_same_test)
```

on top of each view-function?

Comment: use a middleware

Comment: If these are in a class, modify `__getattr__` to always return the decorated method?

Comment: @match `__getattr__` is only invoked as a last resort for unresolved attributes. To make it work on existing attributes you'd have to override `__getattribute__`, which is tricky and will add quite some overhead on each attribute lookup. Better to stick to the standard django way: using a middleware.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505499/how-do-i-set-a-decorator-for-every-one-of-my-django-views

Comment: @match, as stated, these are view functions. I'll give a shot at building middleware (defining process_request(request)) as this seems to be what I need. Thanks so far!

Comment: Not a django user so was only thinking in the general case - now i kmow about it, middleware does seem the right approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. I defined and registered this middleware class to perform the passes_test check. I've copied a bit from the built-in @user_passes_test

```
class RequestIsAuthorizedMiddleware:

  def __init__(self, get_response):
      self.get_response = get_response

  def __call__(self, request): 

      if always_the_same_test(request):
          return self.get_response(request)
      path = request.build_absolute_uri()
      resolved_login_url = resolve_url('/')
      login_scheme, login_netloc = urlparse(resolved_login_url)[:2]
      current_scheme, current_netloc = urlparse(path)[:2]
      if ((not login_scheme or login_scheme == current_scheme) and
              (not login_netloc or login_netloc == current_netloc)):
          path = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') or '/'
      return redirect(path)
```